# Code to find the lag in the consumer offset using kafka library?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I want to get the progress of the kafka consumer i.e. Lag. I know the following commands give me the lag and other valuable description.

`bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.admin.ConsumerGroupCommand --zookeeper localhost:2182 --describe --group DemoConsumer`

`bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --zookeeper localhost:2182 --describe --group DemoConsumer`

I can also get the current consumer offset using following code snippet with the help of kafka-client

```
ConsumerRecords<Integer, String> records = consumer.poll(100);
for (ConsumerRecord<Integer, String> record : records) {

             System.out.println("Received message: (" + record.topic()+ ",
             " + record.partition()+ ", " + record.key() + ", " +
             record.value() + ") at offset " + record.offset());
}
```

But I can't find a code to get the details as the above two commands. Is there any code to find the lag and other details using kafka library?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42203765/5501003), you can get the consumer lag. However, the maven dependency is wrong in that topic, it should be

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>0.10.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And the code is:

```
AdminClient client = AdminClient.createSimplePlaintext("localhost:9092");
Map<TopicPartition, Object> offsets = JavaConversions.asJavaMap(
client.listGroupOffsets("groupID"));
Long offset = (Long) offsets.get(new TopicPartition("topic", 0));
```