# How to get kafka consume lag in java program

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I wrote a java program to consume messsage from kafka. I want to monitor the consume lag, how to get it by java?

BTW, I use:

```
<groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
<artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
<version>0.10.1.1</version>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would add a timestamp to the message when it is written and compare this to the time it was read to get the end to end timing.

Comment: Actually, I want to get the lag count

Comment: what would you use the lag count for?

Comment: I want to check if my consumer is delayed

Comment: in which case I suggest you measure it in milliseconds. A queue which has one message could be ms or mins.

Comment: lag count is measured in number of messages, not milliseconds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I personnaly query directly jmx informations from my consumers. I only consume in java so the JMX beans : `kafka.consumer:type=consumer-fetch-manager-metrics,client-id=*/records-lag-max` are available.

If jolokia is in your classpath you can retrieve the value with a GET on `/jolokia/read/kafka.consumer:type=consumer-fetch-manager-metrics,client-id=*/records-lag-max` and gather all the results in one place.

There is also [Burrow](https://github.com/linkedin/Burrow) which is very easy to configure, but it's a bit outdated (doesn't work for 0.10 if I remember well).

Comment: I checked the jmx, this JMX beans: kafka.server:type=FetcherLagMetrics,name=ConsumerLag,clientId=mygroup,topic=mytpoic,partition=* contains the lag info

Comment: I am running Kafka in a cluster, can you please tell me how to enable and export this specific JMX bean?

Comment: This bean is per consumer client, not for the Kafka cluster itself

Answer (score 13):

In case if you don't want to include kafka (and scala) dependencies to your project you can use class below. It uses only kafka-clients dependencies.

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.OffsetAndMetadata;
import org.apache.kafka.common.PartitionInfo;
import org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.function.BinaryOperator;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class KafkaConsumerMonitor {

    public static class PartionOffsets {
        private long endOffset;
        private long currentOffset;
        private int partion;
        private String topic;

        public PartionOffsets(long endOffset, long currentOffset, int partion, String topic) {
            this.endOffset = endOffset;
            this.currentOffset = currentOffset;
            this.partion = partion;
            this.topic = topic;
        }

        public long getEndOffset() {
            return endOffset;
        }

        public long getCurrentOffset() {
            return currentOffset;
        }

        public int getPartion() {
            return partion;
        }

        public String getTopic() {
            return topic;
        }
    }

    private final String monitoringConsumerGroupID = "monitoring_consumer_" + UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    public Map<TopicPartition, PartionOffsets> getConsumerGroupOffsets(String host, String topic, String groupId) {
        Map<TopicPartition, Long> logEndOffset = getLogEndOffset(topic, host);


        KafkaConsumer consumer = createNewConsumer(groupId, host);

        BinaryOperator<PartionOffsets> mergeFunction = (a, b) -> {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        };

        Map<TopicPartition, PartionOffsets> result = logEndOffset.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        entry -> (entry.getKey()),
                        entry -> {
                            OffsetAndMetadata committed = consumer.committed(entry.getKey());
                            return new PartionOffsets(entry.getValue(), committed.offset(), entry.getKey().partition(), topic);
                        }, mergeFunction));


        return result;
    }

    public Map<TopicPartition, Long> getLogEndOffset(String topic, String host) {
        Map<TopicPartition, Long> endOffsets = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        KafkaConsumer<?, ?> consumer = createNewConsumer(monitoringConsumerGroupID, host);
        List<PartitionInfo> partitionInfoList = consumer.partitionsFor(topic);
        List<TopicPartition> topicPartitions = partitionInfoList.stream().map(pi -> new TopicPartition(topic, pi.partition())).collect(Collectors.toList());
        consumer.assign(topicPartitions);
        consumer.seekToEnd(topicPartitions);
        topicPartitions.forEach(topicPartition -> endOffsets.put(topicPartition, consumer.position(topicPartition)));
        consumer.close();
        return endOffsets;
    }

    private static KafkaConsumer<?, ?> createNewConsumer(String groupId, String host) {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, host);
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        properties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        return new KafkaConsumer<>(properties);
    }
}
```

Comment: OffsetAndMetadata committ;
    for(TopicPartition topicPartition : topicPartitions){
      log.info("topic partion is {}", topicPartition);
      log.info("consumer is {}", consumer.position(topicPartition));
      committ = consumer.committed(topicPartition);
      log.info("commited is {}", committ.offset());         I get offset as null, but all other values are there, can you nudge me in right direction?

Comment: Probably this offset has been expired. Kafka keeps partition data for some period (depends on topic retention policy. In our case it is 7 days). If your consumer never consume data from the topic or the most recent consume was behind this retention period you will get null offset. 

In this case it's up to you how do you define consumer lag. It might be defined as zero (if your Consumer auto.offset.reset setting is latest) or you need to get offset of earliest message in the stream and calculate offset as endOffset-earliestOffset.

Comment: I don't think you can use an assigned consumer to view the committed offsets of a separate subscribed consumer. I think that is why you are getting a null value with the assigned consumer consumer.committed(topicPartition) call. The assigned consumer you've created has probably never itself done a commit

Answer (score 4):

Since version 3.3.x, KafkaConsumer has a method that returns the lag :

```
public OptionalLong currentLag(TopicPartition topicPartition)
```

See https://javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients/latest/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html#currentLag-org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition-

Answer (score 3):

I am using Spring for my api. Using the below code, you can get the metrics via java.The code works.

```
@Component
public class Receiver {

private static final Logger LOGGER =
      LoggerFactory.getLogger(Receiver.class);


@Autowired
private KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry;

  public void testlag() {
      for (MessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer : kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry
                .getListenerContainers()) {
          Map<String, Map<MetricName, ? extends Metric>> metrics = messageListenerContainer.metrics();
          metrics.forEach( (clientid, metricMap) ->{
              System.out.println("------------------------For client id : "+clientid);
              metricMap.forEach((metricName,metricValue)->{
                  //if(metricName.name().contains("lag"))
                  System.out.println("------------Metric name: "+metricName.name()+"-----------Metric value: "+metricValue.metricValue());
              });
          });
            }
  }
```

Comment: In my case, I do not see any metric name that contains "lag"! What exactly is the metric to find consumer lag?

Comment: @AryanVenkat I am seeing the following lag related metrics on the console: i) customers-2.records-lag  ii)customers-2.records-lag-avg   iii)customers-2.records-lag-max . Here customers is the topic name and '2' is the partition.

Answer (score 2):

For you reference, I got this done with the code below. Basically, you have to calculate the lag of each topic-partition manually by calculating the delta between current committed offset and the end offset.

```
private static Map<TopicPartition, Long> lagOf(String brokers, String groupId) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(CommonClientConfigs.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, brokers);
    try (AdminClient client = AdminClient.create(props)) {
        ListConsumerGroupOffsetsResult currentOffsets = client.listConsumerGroupOffsets(groupId);

        try {
            // get current offsets of consuming topic-partitions
            Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> consumedOffsets = currentOffsets.partitionsToOffsetAndMetadata()
                    .get(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            final Map<TopicPartition, Long> result = new HashMap<>();
            doWithKafkaConsumer(groupId, brokers, (c) -> {
                // get latest offsets of consuming topic-partitions
                // lag = latest_offset - current_offset
                Map<TopicPartition, Long> endOffsets = c.endOffsets(consumedOffsets.keySet());
                result.putAll(endOffsets.entrySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(entry -> entry.getKey(),
                        entry -> entry.getValue() - consumedOffsets.get(entry.getKey()).offset())));
            });
            return result;
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException | TimeoutException e) {
            log.error("", e);
            return Collections.emptyMap();
        }
    }
}

public static void doWithKafkaConsumer(String groupId, String brokers,
        Consumer<KafkaConsumer<String, String>> consumerRunner) {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(CommonClientConfigs.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, brokers);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, false);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class.getName());

    try (final KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(props)) {
        consumerRunner.accept(consumer);
    }
}
```

Note that one consumer group could be consuming multiple topics simultaneously, so if you need to get the lag for each topic, you'll have to group and aggregate the result by topic then.

```
    Map<TopicPartition, Long> lags = lagOf(brokers, group);
    Map<String, Long> topicLag = new HashMap<>();
    lags.forEach((tp, lag) -> {
        topicLag.compute(tp.topic(), (k, v) -> v == null ? lag : v + lag);
    });
```

Comment: Can you please include the full class it would be very much healpful

Comment: Thanks a lot, my friend!!  Bingo, Your code worked for me seamlessly!!

Answer (score 1):

Run this standalone code. (Dependency on kafka-clients-2.6.0.jar)

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.function.BinaryOperator;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.OffsetAndMetadata;
import org.apache.kafka.common.PartitionInfo;
import org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer;

public class CosumerGroupLag {

static String host = "localhost:9092";
static String topic = "topic02";
static String groupId = "test-group";

public static void main(String... vj) {
    CosumerGroupLag cgl = new CosumerGroupLag();

    while (true) {
        Map<TopicPartition, PartionOffsets> lag = cgl.getConsumerGroupOffsets(host, topic, groupId);
        System.out.println("$$LAG = " + lag);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private final String monitoringConsumerGroupID = "monitoring_consumer_" + UUID.randomUUID().toString();

public Map<TopicPartition, PartionOffsets> getConsumerGroupOffsets(String host, String topic, String groupId) {
    Map<TopicPartition, Long> logEndOffset = getLogEndOffset(topic, host);

    Set<TopicPartition> topicPartitions = new HashSet<>();
    for (Entry<TopicPartition, Long> s : logEndOffset.entrySet()) {
        topicPartitions.add(s.getKey());
    }
    
    KafkaConsumer<String, Object> consumer = createNewConsumer(groupId, host);
    Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> comittedOffsetMeta = consumer.committed(topicPartitions);

    BinaryOperator<PartionOffsets> mergeFunction = (a, b) -> {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    };
    Map<TopicPartition, PartionOffsets> result = logEndOffset.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(entry -> (entry.getKey()), entry -> {
                OffsetAndMetadata committed = comittedOffsetMeta.get(entry.getKey());
                long currentOffset = 0;
                if(committed != null) { //committed offset will be null for unknown consumer groups
                    currentOffset = committed.offset();
                }
                return new PartionOffsets(entry.getValue(), currentOffset, entry.getKey().partition(), topic);
            }, mergeFunction));

    return result;
}

public Map<TopicPartition, Long> getLogEndOffset(String topic, String host) {
    Map<TopicPartition, Long> endOffsets = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    KafkaConsumer<?, ?> consumer = createNewConsumer(monitoringConsumerGroupID, host);
    List<PartitionInfo> partitionInfoList = consumer.partitionsFor(topic);
    List<TopicPartition> topicPartitions = partitionInfoList.stream()
            .map(pi -> new TopicPartition(topic, pi.partition())).collect(Collectors.toList());
    consumer.assign(topicPartitions);
    consumer.seekToEnd(topicPartitions);
    topicPartitions.forEach(topicPartition -> endOffsets.put(topicPartition, consumer.position(topicPartition)));
    consumer.close();
    return endOffsets;
}

private static KafkaConsumer<String, Object> createNewConsumer(String groupId, String host) {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, host);
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, groupId);
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
    return new KafkaConsumer<>(properties);
}

private static class PartionOffsets {
    private long lag;
    private long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
    private long endOffset;
    private long currentOffset;
    private int partion;
    private String topic;

    public PartionOffsets(long endOffset, long currentOffset, int partion, String topic) {
        this.endOffset = endOffset;
        this.currentOffset = currentOffset;
        this.partion = partion;
        this.topic = topic;
        this.lag = endOffset - currentOffset;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "PartionOffsets [lag=" + lag + ", timestamp=" + timestamp + ", endOffset=" + endOffset
                + ", currentOffset=" + currentOffset + ", partion=" + partion + ", topic=" + topic + "]";
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the SetStatisticsHandler callback function when creating the consumer.
For example, the c# code is as follows

```
var config = new ConsumerConfig()
    {
      BootstrapServers = entrypoints,
      GroupId = groupid,
      EnableAutoCommit = false,
      StatisticsIntervalMs=1000 // statistics interval time
    };

    var consumer = new ConsumerBuilder<Ignore, byte[]>( config )
    .SetStatisticsHandler((consumer,json)=> {
      logger.LogInformation( json ); // statistics metrics, include consumer lag
    } )
    .Build();
```

For details, please refer to statistics metrics in [STATISTICS.md](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/STATISTICS.md).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use AdminClient#listGroupOffsets(groupID) to retrieve offsets of all topic partitions associated with the consumer's group. For example:

```
AdminClient client = AdminClient.createSimplePlaintext("localhost:9092");
Map<TopicPartition, Object> offsets = JavaConversions.asJavaMap(
    client.listGroupOffsets("groupID"));
Long offset = (Long) offsets.get(new TopicPartition("topic", 0));
...
```

**EDIT**:
Snippets above show how to get the committed offset for a given partition. Code below shows how to retrieve LEO for a partition.

```
public long getLogEndOffset(TopicPartition tp) {
    KafkaConsumer consumer = createNewConsumer();
    Collections.singletonList(tp);
    consumer.assign(Collections.singletonList(tp));
    consumer.seekToEnd(Collections.singletonList(tp));
    return consumer.position(tp);
}

private KafkaConsumer<String, String> createNewConsumer() {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "g1");
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, "false");
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.SESSION_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "30000");
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
    return new KafkaConsumer(properties);
}
```

Invoking `getLogEndOffset` returns the LEO for the given partition, then subtract the committed offset from it and the result is the lag.

Comment: Where is the AdminClient come from? can you give me the maven dependency? Thanks very much.

Comment: It comes from kafka.admin package which is already in kafka_2.11 you use.

Comment: This gives the current offset. How can I get the committed offset?