# Display Kafka Consumer Lag using java

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am not able to get any solution to print Kafka consumer Lag.

./kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.ConsumerOffsetChecker --group   test-group --zookeeper localhost:2181 --topic test01

Group           Topic   Pid Offset   logSize   Lag Owner
test-group      test01  0   7         9        2   test-group_Jitendra-E5530-1497519128391-bdea2e0c-0

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42201616/how-to-get-kafka-consume-lag-in-java-program/42203765?noredirect=1#comment76085392_42203765

Comment: If you need consumer lag just for monitoring you can use these tools:
1.[KafkaOffserMonitor]( https://github.com/quantifind/KafkaOffsetMonitor)
2. https://github.com/linkedin/Burrow
First one is written in Java, so you can check out sources.

Comment: @gorros I have already this thing, but i want to check through Java

Comment: @amethystic Its is working with Kafka 0.10.2 but i want 0.8.2.2 ,Actually it is not supporting this Api