# How to get a Kafka Topic Lag in Java

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I want to see the lag position of a kafka topic in java. someone here says that below code will work.

```
AdminClient client = AdminClient.createSimplePlaintext("localhost:9092");
Map<TopicPartition, Object> offsets = JavaConversions.asJavaMap(
client.listGroupOffsets("groupID"));
Long offset = (Long) offsets.get(new TopicPartition("topic", 0));
```

But when I tried to import **kafka.admin.AdminClient** that **listGroupOffsets** method is not there. Please help me with this.

Comment: What's the server version you use? `listGroupOffsets` is accessible from within the user application code with 1.0.0.

Comment: my kafka version is 0.8. but I added Kafka kafka_2.10-0.10.0.0.jar for AdminClient dependency. In that I'm not getting that listGroupOffsets method. Please help me with this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get kafka consume lag in java program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42201616/how-to-get-kafka-consume-lag-in-java-program)

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://github.com/yahoo/kafka-manager and can use their http Rest APIs to get consumer groups lag and other details.

Comment: Thanks. But I want that topic lag by java code. How can I get the lag by java code?

Comment: @KoteswaraRaoBalijepalli Yes they expose the endpoints http://127.0.0.1:8080/kafka/api/status/kafkaClusterName/kafkaConsumerGroupName/KF/groupSummary .

Refer to the below mentioned links : 
https://github.com/yahoo/kafka-manager/issues/414
https://github.com/jgritman/httpbuilder/wiki/GET-Examples

Answer (score 0):

Method `listGroupOffsets` was introduced to `AdminClient.scala` starting 0.10.2. See [KAFKA-3853](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3853) for details. So you should use Kafka 0.10.2.0 or upwards.

Comment: Thanks. But my kafka version is 0.8, in this version how can i get the lag by using java code?

Comment: It's nearly impossible for 0.8 brokers to understand or handle the requests sent by 0.10 code. An alternative way to do this is to write code to get the lag directly from Zookeeper, although you could only get the committed offsets. Is it possible for you to upgrade to a newer version?

Answer (score 0):

I am using Spring framework. Using the below code, you can get the metrics via java.The code works.

```
@Component
public class Receiver {

private static final Logger LOGGER =
  LoggerFactory.getLogger(Receiver.class);


@Autowired
private KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry;

  public void testlag() {
  for (MessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer : kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry
            .getListenerContainers()) {
      Map<String, Map<MetricName, ? extends Metric>> metrics = messageListenerContainer.metrics();
      metrics.forEach( (clientid, metricMap) ->{
          System.out.println("------------------------For client id : "+clientid);
          metricMap.forEach((metricName,metricValue)->{
              //if(metricName.name().contains("lag"))
              System.out.println("------------Metric name: "+metricName.name()+"-----------Metric value: "+metricValue.metricValue());
          });
      });
        }
  }
```