# How to get Consumer Lag for a consumer group in kafka in java

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-platform

I want to know the consumer lag for a consumer group using java.
I have tried using

```
kafka-consumer-groups --describe --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --group MyGroupName
```

and the lag is visible.

How do i do this in Java ?

I have tried using the `org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClient`, but could not get the lag per consumer group.

i am using 
`confluent 5.0.1 which has kafka 2.0.1
org.apache.kafka - kafka-clients - 2.0.1`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get kafka consume lag in java program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42201616/how-to-get-kafka-consume-lag-in-java-program)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lag is approximately `endOffset-currentOffset`. You can use

```
AdminClient.listConsumerGroupOffsets("MyGroupName").partitionsToOffsetAndMetadata()
```

to get the current offset for the group. To get the end offsets you need to create KafkaConsumer for the topic and use

```
KafkaConsumer.endOffsets(partitions)
```

Comment: More detailed answer is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42201616/how-to-get-kafka-consume-lag-in-java-program.