# Is there any api to find partition is balanced or not in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

Is there any API or client library exist which can tell me how much percent topic is filled with data so that I can figure out is there any way to check whether partitions are balanced or not

Answer (score 2):

This is a good strategy to discuss before designing and development on Kafka.

The first point you need to consider how you are defining your key and whats exactly partitioner you are planning to use while producing a message to the topics.

Thumb-rule:

1. If you not bothering collecting messages in different groups based on key just pass the key as null to redistribute your messages in a round-robin manner.
2. You can also use a custom partitioner to define partitioning in case you need to do some more refinement.

To check the partition distribution, the best approach is to check the lagging on each partition and rate byte/sec

There many ways to monitor

1.You can use simple API to get various matrices like lagging, rate, etc

You can refer here   [Kafka Metrices](https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka/monitoring.html)

```
kafka.server:type=ReplicaFetcherManager,name=MaxLag,clientId=Replica
```

2.I generally prefer Grafana with JMX exported it will visualize matrices

[Grafana](https://medium.com/activewizards-machine-learning-company/kafka-monitoring-with-prometheus-telegraf-and-grafana-6228fed736f1)

3.We can also use CLI to identify each partition offset and lagging, and really give you the overall figure instantly

```
bin/kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server broker1:9092 --describe --group consumer-group


TOPIC                          PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG        CONSUMER-ID                                       HOST                           CLIENT-ID
 test                              1          10               30           20         consumer-group
```

4. You can also do with programmatically
   [How to identify partition lagging](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42201616/how-to-get-kafka-consume-lag-in-java-program/42203765?noredirect=1#comment76085392_42203765)
5. Confluent Control-Center is paid one but a very interesting tool to monitor overall Kafka including consumer and its partitions/
   [Confluent control center](https://www.confluent.io/confluent-control-center/)

Answer (score 0):

Assume that you created a topic X. Your producers started to push tons of data into your topic. Your topic is growing exponentially. Depending on the configuration **log.segment.bytes**, Kafka will create a new segment and start writing data into it. Old segment will be kept for **log.retention.ms** milliseconds. Because of this, 100% of a topic itself is tricky calculate.

However, if you are looking for a tool that can allocate partitions depending on the load on each broker then I would recommend looking into Kafka-kit (https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/engineering/introducing-kafka-kit-tools-for-scaling-kafka/).

Comment: I'm not looking for a tool that can allocate partitions depending on the load on each broker rather I want to find a current partition or topic capacity using some script or through any program

Comment: A producer sends (key,value)+more in message. Key can be a customerId. Having all the data about one customer in one partition makes the design more reliable. Now, let's say partitionX is hosted on hostA and it is overloaded then producer should not try to be smart and start sending message to partitionY. If a hostA overloads and shuts down then Kafka will start using in-sync replicas.