# How to check the progress status of the messages in kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have designed the REST Post API in java which actually publishes the message to particular Kafka topic, lets say its "ProductTopic".

In the background, a microservice is listening to this "ProductTopic" topic and start to consume the message and saves to DB. Now i would like write a GET REST API to see the progress(which gives the output of job) of the job, like how much messages are  successfully consumed and how is still pending. So that end user will have an idea about what's happening.

Is there a way to achieve this ? I did searched a lot in google, all i see was the command line query to see the consumption of the messages. Not any java implementation example available from confluent side. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check consumer lag for the consumer group of your service. Lag is approximately `endOffset-currentOffset`. You can find examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42201616/how-to-get-kafka-consume-lag-in-java-program)

Comment: Hi, i did implemented that from the example. i have doubt. For example now consumer is at offset 5, does this me other 4 have been consumed successfully?

Comment: Offset is defined per partition. If the committed offset in one of the partitions is 5, it means that all the messages with the offset, less or equal than 5 from that partition are consumed.

Comment: Ok Thank you. i got it... Is it possible to which offset has been triggered from what request? For example let say request-1 added 5 messages to kafka. request-2 added 5 messages to kafka. Now when i get currentOffset and endOffset, i want to know to which  request these offset belongs to.

Comment: No, you cannot add any metadata for the offsets